# Problems occurred while trying to save the state of the workbench in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, save, workspace

I have a problem each time I close Eclipse (Helios Release 1 in Windows Vista). This is the error log:

Problems occurred while trying to save the state of the workbench.
  Problems occurred during save.
    Problems while saving variables and containers
    C:\Users...(workspace dir)....metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core\variablesAndContainers.dat (Access Denied)

When I started using Eclipse I used to have the workspace in different directory. Then I moved it to a different location. On loading the workspace it works correct.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To fix go to your workspace and delete the .metadata folder. Restart eclipse and point it to where the old workspace was and load projects using File -> New.

You can only load one by one but at least it solved the issues

Comment: I just override the all workspace folder from my partner computer (with the .metadata). Delete the .metadata folder and import existing  projects from workspace solved the problem. 10x!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the problems is now solved. I managed to do that in an unorthodox (in my opinion) way. It seemed that there was an access problem. Eclipse didn't have access to its own .dat files. Probably because of some windows-eclipse misunderstanding. I tried to delete the files that were making an error and Eclipse created them again. Like that, problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

Best way is looking into WORKSPACE/.metadata/.log where Eclipse spits out all everything what's wrong. Maybe there is just one small file to kill or unlock. So you don't need to import all former projects from scratch

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by going into:

```
workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.jdt.core\.org.eclipse.jdt.core.external.folders
```

I unhid the .project file and granted permission to the file for system, admins etc.

My problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the problem is the same but in my case was the Controlled folder access in the windows defender that was the source of my error.

I turned off in the Virus @ Thread protection settings and restarted eclipse and was OK.

Answer (score 0):

I was fixed it.

1. Copy your project from this drive to another drive.
2. Then, you need to delete your project in the old data.
3. Copy the project again from the copied drive (step 1) to the old drive.
   And now, restart Eclipse and run your project.
   Good luck!